# Using arrow notation for pointing to each dimension of a multidimensional vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, vector

I want to use a pointer to a 2D vector (matrix) in some function that traverses all the rows and columns like this:

```
int do_stuff_to_matrix(vector< vector<int> > *matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*matrix)[0].size(); j++) {
            // do something for each element of matrix  
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Using -> notation, I can get the size of one dimension of the matrix that my pointer points to. But I wasn't sure if I could use the same notation for the 2nd dimension, which is why I wrote it out using the normal * operator.

Is a way I can rewrite "(*matrix)[0].size()" using -> notation?

Comment: If you do not need to refer to array indexes, `i`, and `j`, inside the loop, then using C++11 range iteration will be cleaner, and more compact and render this whole question moot.

Comment: You don't check at the start of the function if the pointer is null.  If you know it's never null, why use a pointer at all?  I would change the function to take a `vector<vector<int>>& matrix` to be clearer (and as a bonus side effect, the ugly notation goes away too).

Answer (score 1):

`matrix->operator[](0).size()`

I wouldn't advise it.